# Is there any way how to refer actual column name as variable in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am new to Power Query and I would like to ask more experienced people about it.

I am trying to solve problem with Text.Combine where I would like to combine together value in specific column and column name of actual cell.

Do you have any idea?

My idea is formula similar to this:

```
=Text.Combine({[kod], Column.Name},";")
```

Thank you very much for answer.

Tomas

Edit 8.12.2021:

@horseyride

I actually try fill columns automatically with data in following format where first part will be value from actual row and actual column name:

For e.g.:

8M0183:F01A0101.B in first row, second column,

8M0182:F01A0102.A in second row, first column

Table example mentioned bellow.
[image: Table example]

Thank you very much for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works for you.  It combines the KOD column with the column name into each null cell, for every column that is not named KOD

It finds all column not named KOD.  It converts those to text.  It replaces all nulls with a placeholder, here "xxx". We unpivot to get everything to just three columns.  We then combine the column title and the cell contents if the cell contents is equal to the placeholder. Pivot to get back to original format

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ColumnList=List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"KOD"}),
ConvertToText=  Table.TransformColumnTypes (Source,List.Transform(ColumnList, each {_ , type text})),
ReplaceNullsWithPlaceholder = Table.ReplaceValue(ConvertToText,null,"xxx",Replacer.ReplaceValue,ColumnList),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(ReplaceNullsWithPlaceholder, {"KOD"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
CombineColumnAndRow = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value2", each if [Value]="xxx" then [Attribute]&":"&[KOD] else [Value]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(CombineColumnAndRow,{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value2")
in #"Pivoted Column1"
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated main question with more details. Can you please look on it? Thank you very much.